# How edit more than 2 object in one template?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a student journal for teachers, where the teacher can enter scores for all students in this discipline. How can I update student scores? Do I need to create many forms or what?
Thx for you answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to create a table or similar with "Save" button for each student so you may update them separately if needed. For example you can create a table similar to this:

```
Name:  Math  Biology Sports

Peter    6     3        6      SAVE_BUTTON
Anne     4     4        4      SAVE_BUTTON
John     5     6        6      SAVE_BUTTON
```

It would be annoying if you have only one SAVE button and if some results are not ready yet but you need to fill the others. Also, this would avoid errors. For example separate save buttons would save the information for one student only and if you populate another student's field by  mistake, it wouldn't update.

Next, upon clicking the SAVE button you would need to use JS to get that information and perform an AJAX call to save the student's grades.

Comment: I try to save the marks using AJAX, when the teacher enters the tag and defocuses the cell, I send an Ajax request. What do you think about this method, will this method work?

Comment: This might work but each time a cell is "defocused" it would fire a save event which might not be the desired result and I would not use .